# Select parent through child element via ID in jquery?

Tags: jquery, parent

I have a button in a form with a unique ID. I'm trying to select the form that button is in using the ID of the button. Something like:

```
    $('#submitButton').parent;
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: doesn't this work? $('#submitButton')[0].parentNode;

Comment: You are almost there, http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) is a function:

```
var $parent = $('#submitButton').parent();
```

You will find most of the jQuery API is made of functions and not properties.

You can also get at the underlying DOM object (and therefore its properties) using `$('#submitButton')[0].somepropertyname` but not recommended if you are already using jQuery.

based on the wording of your question you probably should use `closest` instead:

e.g.

```
var $form = $('#submitButton').closest('form');
```

jQuery's [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) returns the nearest matching object from the list of ancestors *and* the object itself.